# Visibility and order of atomic counter updates vs blocking queues

Tags: java, concurrency, visibility, atomic

If a producer thread adds an object to one of several BlockingQueue:s, and following that increments an atomic integer. Will a consumer thread ever see the incremented integer value before it can poll each BlockingQueue and find the queued object?

The documentation says that there is a *happens-before* relationship with reading a counter. So my understanding is that the consumer thread should always see the added items in the blocking queue.

I have a difficult bug where it appears as if consumer threads see the incremented integer first, but they can never find any object in the blocking queues that they poll (because poll returns null for all the queues). All the producer threads follow the "add to queue then increment counter" behavior.

Alternatively, there are undocumented reasons why you can get null back from polling a BlockingQueue, other than the queue being empty.

(If it matters, I'm seeing this with a java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.)

Comment: Is the counter decremented after the items are removed from the queues? When and by which thread? It seems like there could be races between the state of the counter and the state of the queues. Posting code would help.

Answer (score 1):

The happens-before relationship in this case is *the add into the queue happens before the write to the atomic integer*.

To be able to ensure the relationship, one thread needs to know the atomic integer has changed or there is an association between an atomic integer's value and the queue's current state.

It's too hard to tell what the error is based on your description, but simply reading an atomic integer's value means nothing unless you know it has changed (or hasn't depending on the relationship).

As far as returning null.  LinkedBlockingQueue can return null if you invoke a non-waiting method.  For instance `poll` is non-waiting

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this
>   queue is empty.

Where as `take` will wait for an element to exist in the queue

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.